# Configuration fields in backend are all disabled

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

After updating Magento 2.1 to Magento 2.2 all fields in backend under "Default Config" are disabled. If I switch to Main Website or one of stores the fields can be edited.

Currently running Magento 2.2 with 1 website which contains 3 stores.

[image: Sample fields]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue without reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `app/etc/config.php` Remove the unnecessary configuration.
Make it look like this

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        'modules' => [
        'Magento_Store' => 1,
        'Magento_Directory' => 1,
        'Magento_Eav' => 1,
        ...
        'Vertex_Tax' => 1,
    ]
];
```

Then run

```
bin/magento app:config:import
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Already solved this, but your anwser could help someone....

Answer (score 1):

It was a miscommunication problem in team. It seems that someone ran `magento app:config:dump` before me, which consequently locked all config entries in database.

You can read more about this here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/live/sens-data-over.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying to unlock admin settings locked out can sometimes become an episode of chasing one's own tail, I mean never ending and takes you round and round!

I found modifying values of locked fields using CLI very easy.

Please refer this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html